# Converting SQL query into KnexJS

Tags: sql, knex.js

I am trying to convert SQL query into KnexJS format, but current KnexJS query gives me the following error.

- syntax error at or near "as" stack: error: syntax error at or near "as"

Here are the original query and the one I've been working on for the KnexJS. 
Please correct my KnexJS query.

Thank you in advance!

Original SQL query:

```
select count(distinct date) 
from task_history
where 
store_id = 100 and date >
(select date from (
select date, count(*) as count_all, count(case when finish_time is not null 
then 1 else null end) as count_finished
from task_history
where store_id = 100 
group by date
order by count_finished, date desc
fetch first row only) as get_max_date)
```

KnexJS query:

```
.table("task_history")
.count(db.raw("'distinct date'"))
.where('store_id', 100)
.where('date', '>', function() {
    this.select('date')
    .from(function() {
        this.select('date')
        .table("task_history")
        .first()
        .count('* as count_all')
        .count(db.raw(`case when finish_time is not null then 1 else null end as count_finished`))
        .where('store_id', 100)
        .groupBy('date')
        .orderBy('count_finished', 'desc')
        .orderBy('date', 'desc')
        .as('get_max_date')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The following query worked for me: 

.table("task_history")
  .count(db.raw("distinct date"))
  .where('store_id', 100)
  .where('date', '>', function() {
    this.select('date')
      .from(function() {
        this.select('date')
          .table("task_history")
          .first()
          .count('* as count_all')
          .select( db.raw("count(case when finish_time is not null then 1 else null end) as count_finished"))
          .where('store_id', 100)
          .groupBy('date')
          .orderBy('count_finished', 'asc')
          .orderBy('date', 'desc')
          .as('get_max_date')
      })
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a complex query. Since you haven't shared the SQL structure for others to attempt the same query, I would suggest that you try including this 'debugging' clause in your query:

```
.on('query-error', function(ex, obj) {
    console.log("KNEX query-error ex:", ex, "obj:", obj);
})
```

This will output the generated SQL for you when the query crashes. That may show you which part of the statement is incorrect.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you GaryL.Actually, I have figured it out myself but still have a question for the following part of the query. 
    .count(db.raw('case when finish_time is not null then 1 else null end'))
        I wanted to make alias there and tried some ways, but none of em worked.
        Here are 3 cases I tried.Could you please tell me how to make alias there ?

Comment: .count(db.raw('case when finish_time is not null then 1 else null end as count_finished'))
            .count(db.raw('(case when finish_time is not null then 1 else null end) as count_finished'))
            .count(db.raw("('case when finish_time is not null then 1 else null end') as count_finished')")

Comment: `.select( db.raw("count(case when finish_time is not null then 1 else null end) as count_finished"))` ... The knex `.count()` statement adds a parenthesis layer that is messing you up.